# What does "free(): double free detected in tcache 2" mean?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I was writing a program for doing polynomial addition in C. I'm having some problems using `free()`. I have figured out a solution but I don't know what's happening in the background.

I'm uploading the complete files (instead of code snippet). Here's the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Ankan-Basu/Polynomial-Question-for-StackOverflw).  I've included the correct version as `polynomial.c` and the incorrect version as `polynomial_uncorrected.c`. The problem is in line 41-42 in `polynomial_uncorrected.c`.

I run the program.
If none of `p1` and `p2` are 0 polynomials, then the program is running correctly. If any one of `p1` or `p2` is a zero polynomial (all elements are entered as 0), I'm running into the following problem.

```
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Valgrind shows the following output

```
==11720== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11720== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11720== Using Valgrind-3.16.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11720== Command: ./p_c.out
==11720== 
FIRST POLYNOMIAL :
Enter degree of polynomial : 2
Enter coefficient of x^2 : 1
Enter coefficient of x^1 : 2
Enter coefficient of x^0 : 3

SECOND POLYNOMIAL :
Enter degree of polynomial : 0
Enter coefficient of x^0 : 0

FIRST POLYNOMIAL :
1x^2 + 2x + 3

SECOND POLYNOMIAL :
0

SUM :
1x^2 + 2x + 3
==11720== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==11720==    at 0x483A9AB: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:538)
==11720==    by 0x1092F2: main (in /<path>/p_c.out)
==11720==  Address 0x4a4b960 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==11720==    at 0x483A9AB: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:538)
==11720==    by 0x1092CC: main (in /<path>/p_c.out)
==11720==  Block was alloc'd at
==11720==    at 0x483BD7B: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:834)
==11720==    by 0x1093D8: inp_pol (in /<path>/p_c.out)
==11720==    by 0x10920B: main (in /<path>/p_c.out)
==11720== 
==11720== 
==11720== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11720==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11720==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 6 frees, 2,096 bytes allocated
==11720== 
==11720== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==11720== 
==11720== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==11720== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I thought p3 was not being allocated so i realloc-ed

```
p3 = realloc (p3, (*size3)*sizeof(element));
```

These lines are still present as comments in the code (polynomial_uncorrected.c). But I got the same error.

Then I realised I should `free(p3)` only if both `p1` and `p2` are not NULL (ie, not zero polynomial). And it worked, but I don't know why.

**Why was it saying double free detected in tcache 2?**

Comment: BTW your editor is broken. As seen on the github, tabstops are there at 8. Either always use tabs only for indent, or convert to spaces at desired number.

FWIW, the question should be mostly self-contained. Compile with debug information (`-g`), so you will get line numbers too.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yes. it solved it. if p2 is NULL, p3 = p1. i'm already doing free(p1) before. so no need to do free(p3). same if p1 is NULL and p2 is not NULL. (then p3=p2). compiling with -g flag helped me figure this out. THANKS.
yes. i also think my editor(Geany) is broken. I saved with TABS, later when i opened my file (with Geany )I saw the TABS had turned into SPACES. I tried opening with Atoms. saw that TABS have not turned into SPACES. ;(